# конвертор валют jQuery ,как получить значение из валюты из селект бокса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу конвертор грн -> валюту которую  выберет юзер из селект бокса
как получить значение той валюты из json которую выберет пользователь из селекта 
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form  id="form">
        <input type="text" class="input">введите сумму<br>
        <select  id="select">
            <option value="disabled">выберите валюту</option>
        </select>
        <button class='button'>конвертировать</button><br>
        <input type="text">result
    </form>
    <script src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
var $form = $('#form');
    $form.on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
    url:'https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json',
    success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
$.each(data,function(i,a){
    $('#select').append($('<option>').text(a.txt));
})
            }
    });

$('.button').click(function(){
    console.log('ready');
    // var $res= $('.input').val()*  ????
});
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data,function(i,a){
  $('#select').append($('<option>').text(a.txt).val(a.rate));
});
...

$('.button').click(function(){
  var res = $('.input').val() * $('#select').val();
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: оно будет брать название валюты ,но не её значение

Comment: @ЛёшаСугуров Пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее.